# select calculation for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to create a calculation from results in a database query to provide a sort of relevance.

Here's an example of my query:

```
SELECT d.id, MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as r_matches, s.total_matches
FROM days d
LEFT JOIN condition_days r
    ON (d.id = r.day_id AND MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ss.day_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ss.condition_id) as total_matches FROM conditions ss WHERE ss.condition_id IN (4, 13, 20) GROUP BY ss.day_id) s
ON (s.day_id = d.id)
```

Which returns something like this:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| id  | r_matches | total_matches |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| 540 |         2 |             5 |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
```

So my question is, how do I get a calculation of the 2 calculated fields (r_matches and total_matches)?
This is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| id  | r_matches | total_matches | total                                        |
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 540 |         2 |             3 | 5 (calculation of total_matches + r_matches) |
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

So is there a way to get a calculated total from 2 calculated fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't test run without schemas, but something like this using temporary variables should do it just fine;

```
SELECT 
  d.id, 
  @tmp := (MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as r_matches, 
  s.total_matches,
  s.total_matches + @tmp AS total
FROM days d
LEFT JOIN condition_days r
  ON (d.id = r.day_id AND MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ss.day_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ss.condition_id) as total_matches 
  FROM conditions ss WHERE ss.condition_id IN (4, 13, 20) GROUP BY ss.day_id) s
ON (s.day_id = d.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a derived table:

```
   select id, r_matches, total_matches, r_matches + total_matches as total
   from (
       select d.id,
              MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as r_matches,
              s.total_matches as total_matches
       ...
   ) as dt;
```

The query engine might be smart enough to only compute the MATCH once even if it is mentioned twice so the simple-minded approach:

```
select d.id, 
       MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as r_matches, 
       s.total_matches,
       MATCH (r.text) AGAINST('sleet snow rain' IN BOOLEAN MODE) + s.total_matches as total
...
```

might work just fine. I don't know if MySQL will recognize the duplicate MATCH though.